# Icons and nautilius windows looks strange

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

Desktop icons and nautilus window (all file browsing) looks colorless and low resolution.
"`nautilius -q`" provides a remedy. However, I need to do it after each boot...

Problem appeared after updating to 11.10.
I have nvidia-graphics if it matters...

Many thanks in advance!
Please let me know if I should provide any log. Don't know where to start, due to noob!

Comment: Have the same issue, thanks for the nautilus -q tip

Comment: Have an nvidia card and same problem. It sometimes goes away and then comes back. Am having it right now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This occurred after I installed the proprietary NVidia drivers.

For me I had to launch nvidia-settings from the command line and tweak a few resolution settings and save this to my `x.config` file. This is the only way that things become persisted between logins.

You might look at settings using xrandr before and after using your "nautilus -q" tip. I'm not really sure what the base issue is, but I and several of my friends have noticed problems with nautilus looking a little too "old school" with the latest nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Please try setting all monitor options to default (in nvidia-settings) and replacing (not merging) old xorg.conf with new one.